# How to connect in case Azure Cosmos DB default force use TLS/SSL?

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb

My case:
Client: Windows 10 x64. pgAdmin 4 version 8.4 (latest).

Server: Cloud Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL burstable, version 16.

[image]

My connection string will be likes this

```
jdbc:postgresql://c-donhuvycluster.qs4vulsae3t7uz.postgres.cosmos.azure.com:5432/vydb?user=citus&password={your_password}&sslmode=require
```

```
Encrypted connections

This cluster enforces encrypted connections using Transport Layer Security (TLS). For information on TLS version and certificates, refer to connecting with TLS/SSL.
```

How to connect in case Azure Cosmos DB default force use TLS/SSL? Please guide me. I search video tutorial on YouTube but did not see.

I did not know how to face with `sslmode=require` .

My workaround: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/postgresql/howto-ssl-connection-security#applications-that-require-certificate-verification-for-tls-connectivity

https://www.virtuozzo.com/company/blog/establish-secure-ssl-connection-to-postgresql-database-server/

but I did know how to get certificate from Azure?

Answer (score 0):

No need do anything more.

[image]

at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/postgresql/howto-ssl-connection-security   , I seen a link for downloading https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem , but no need using??